# Mule ESB Disaster Recovery Strategy

Tags: mule

Can you help me with this specific mule esb question related to DR stategy. What needs to be done with regard to the architecture/design and redundancies built into the Mule ESB so that recovery from disaster to reduce the total outage time. If you could give me some pointers as to how this needs to be done in Mule ESB.

Answer (score 0):

This is more related only based on the implementation . There is a lot of features that Mule ESB as a container provides .

You can get some insights from the below links

http://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/ha-importance-esb

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Persisting+Environment+Data

There can be disaster in two meanings. One is when the system of the server box as such is down another is when some natural disaster happens.

In above links you can get info on reducing the first type of disaster issues.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question . As a first point i can say that Mule ESB is stateless object, so the data persistence and server recovery mechanisms will not be same as other integration tools (like Tibco,Oracle SOA).

If you want really store the transaction data you can use the interceptor and notification mechanisms and customizing the logging location. We have implemented this.

or you can configure the external db connectivity to store it.